# Fetch kraken in C# WEB API and return it to client in different structure

Tags: c#

I have a problem with returning a Kraken JSON structure back to the client from this URL: https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btcusd/ohlc . Also I need to show the prices in last 60mins in Angular from that JSON URL.

This is my code for now that i have.

````
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace btc
{

    class Program
    {
        HttpClient client= new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            await program.GetTodoItems();
        }

        private async Task GetTodoItems()
        {
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(
               "https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btcusd/ohlc");

            Console.WriteLine(response);

            Root krakenResult= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);

            var price_data_kraken = krakenResult.result;

            

            Console.WriteLine(price_data_kraken);
            
        }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public List<List<double>> _14400 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _180 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _1800 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _21600 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _259200 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _300 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _3600 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _43200 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _60 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _604800 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _604800_Monday { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _7200 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _86400 { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> _900 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }
} ```

Please help me.
````

Comment: You said "_I have a problem with returning a Kraken JSON_" but you did not tell what problem it was... Check the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and specially the awesome [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) inside.

Comment: My program gives me back the same structure like it is on the URL I pasted here and that's the problem. I don't know hot to get back readable structure and parse it to the client.

Comment: When I parse your JSON code online there is no '_' before the variable names. Try renaming '_900' into just '900'.

Comment: It has to be with _, the other way it doesnt recognize its initialization.

Comment: I copy-pasted your json into [json to c#](https://json2csharp.com/) and it gave me two classes, not one...